# Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am getting this error while creating the lightning web component. Component files were created successfully but this error popped up. How to solve it or should I ignore it.

> 12:26:51.167 Starting SFDX: Create Lightning Web Component cannot open
> file:///home/Training/Calculator/force-app/main/default/lwc/Calculator/Calculator.js.
> Detail: Unable to read file
> '/home/Training/Calculator/force-app/main/default/lwc/Calculator/Calculator.js'
> (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file
> '/home/Training/Calculator/force-app/main/default/lwc/Calculator/Calculator.js')

***Other Details:***

OS: Linux Mint
VS code version: 1.63.2 (03/Jan/2022)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWC component names should start with a lower case character. From what I can tell this is the reason for your problem. I suggest "calculator".

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_folder):

> The folder and its files must follow these naming rules.
>
> - Must begin with a lowercase letter

Don't ask me why there's no better error message than the one you got (or why this is not enforced in the first place).